# Why are we not having : "SAVE AS SITE TEMPLATE" in publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, publishing

We are not having option to SAVE THE SITE AS TEMPLATE if we are having PUBLISHING SITE ENABLED on a SharePoint site.

If we are de-activating this feature, we can get that option to save the site as template.

Is this right approach to do?
If so, Will we create any problem in re-activating the publishing feature?
What problems will get produce if we de-activate the publishing feature?

Comment: Only teamsite and project site have the ability to save it as template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue most frequently occurs because the Community Sites or the SharePoint Server Publishing feature is currently enabled or was previously enabled for the affected site.

SharePoint doesn’t support creating a template from a site where publishing or community features were enabled. This is because the publishing feature creates site elements that are not supported as part of a template, and these elements remain even when the feature is disabled. This also includes templates that were created through SharePoint Designer.

**Note** Although the **Save site as template** option may become available after you deactivate publishing features, it is still unsupported to create a template from a site that has ever had publishing features enabled. If you create a site from this template, you may encounter problems when you try to activate publishing on the new site. For example, you may receive the following error message:

> Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site
>   properties for Web at Url: '......' OriginalException: Failed to
>   compare two elements in the array.

Microsoft has explained it brilliantly at their support site, read in detail [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2492356)

**Update**:

Even after that if you are keen to save site as template keeping your Publishing Feature activated, then refer [Save SharePoint 2013 publishing site as a template](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/13/save-sharepoint-2013-publishing-site-as-a-template/)

Answer (score 2):

By Default **Save site as template** is disabled for publishing site. So to enable this, first you have to change value of "**SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled**" from `false` to `true`.

Steps:

1. Open Your site in SharePoint Designer.
2. In ribbon control, there is option **Site Options**
3. Click on that. It will open parameters window.
4. Find **SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled** in parameters list.
5. Select it and click on **modify** button.
6. Change value to `true`.
7. Ok & Apply.

Now try **/publishingsite/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx**. It will allow you to save your site as template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to de-activate the publishing feature to save site as template.

Instead, go to Site Settings, and click on the URL in the address bar. Remove "/_layouts/settings.aspx" from the URL and replace it with: "/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx"

You will then be able to save the site as template without deactivating the publishing feature.

Comment: No.That will not work.


Below is the error message : 
Sorry, something went wrong
The "Save site as template" action is not supported on this site.

Comment: You need to remove all the external apps before creating the template. The publishing site can be templated, but not the ones having apps