# How to replicate a publishing site in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I am having a SharePoint site which is having some Site Pages and some other doc library.

**Site pages --> This is form library for holding the pages
           --> These pages are created in a way that it had one script editor webpart + one content editor webpart.**

Now, I want to ***replicate this site***. Meaning

- 1) All the site pages with its content need to created in the new
  site.

I am not having SAVE AS TEMPLATE to save the site.

Is there any other options to do so?

on the other hand, if this approach is not possible to replicate, then what are the other approaches available. I believe we can do this with the help of : Page Layout functionality.

Please provide your suggestions on this...

Comment: You have used both the enterprise and online tag. Is it on premise or online? If it's on-premise you could use PowerShell to copy the whole site collection.

Answer (score 2):

The publishing sites are not saved as Templates straight forward. But in some cases you save it as a template but there are some work around for that, read [Why are we not having : “SAVE AS SITE TEMPLATE” in publishing site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174105/why-are-we-not-having-save-as-site-template-in-publishing-site).

My take on your situation:

1. Looking at your requirement, I am assuming you just need to copy all the pages to another publishing site.
2. Just for this I would not save site as template and create another.
3. Your idea of using Page Layouts is good. You can deploy the same Page Layout on new site.
4. If your number of pages are more, then create a PowerShell script and automate creating of Pages. Refer [CSOM PowerShell to create a SharePoint publishing page with custom or OOB page layout](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/csom-powershell-to-create-a-sharepoint-publishing-page-with-custom-or-oob-page-layout/)

Comment: Thanks Asad Refai for you suggestion. I cannot use powershell since SP environment is ONLINE. So no powershell, no SP designer.
Only with the DESIGNER MANAGER, I need to check for "PAGE LAYOUT" solution.

Comment: You use PowerShell script for Online version as well. The script link which I have given is the CSOM i.e. can be used for Online. You just need to update the way you connect to SPO.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to replicate content... but I will talk about the "structural" ones, the ones which would achieve your requirements.

I would consider some of the below:

1 - STSADM Export/Import 
Literally downloads your content and upload the content to the brand new destination. (But I think you can have some trouble with webparts in pages. But worth a try)

2 - STS/Powershell Backup/Restore
You can backup your site collection and restore it into another webapplication/new site collection.

3 - Hard code Powershell script 
You can try to develop some script to export/import if you need to achieve something very specific.

If you are considering this move between locations in the same farm, the 3 options should work.

PS: There is also the SQLServer backup/restore method, but I don't think this approach is necessary here.

Comment: question is about the SharePoint online, are you sure these options available for him